# Shadow in collectionview cell is not acting the same way as the other cells in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, shadow

I am trying to create a shadow on a collectionview cell using diffable data source, and I can do that, but the problem is that on some of the cells the shadow is different than the other cells.

[image]

I want it to look like the second cell down, where the shadow has a small shadow around the whole cell, instead of looking like the first cell where the shadow is at the bottom.

This is the extension I created for the shadow:

```
    extension UIView {
    
    func shadowSetUp() {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        clipsToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
    
}
```

I put this extension in the collectionview cell view, like so:

```
    private lazy var setUpView: Void = {
        contentView.addSubview(cellBackground)
        cellBackground.addSubview(title)
        cellBackground.addSubview(imgView)
        cellBackground.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.clipsToBounds = false
        contentView.backgroundColor = colors.Colors.views
        cellBackground.backgroundColor = colors.Colors.views
        title.textColor = .label
        title.numberOfLines = 3
        title.textAlignment = .left
        title.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        title.font = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold))
        title.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        title.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        
        title.isHidden = true
        imgView.isHidden = true

        cellBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        contentView.shadowSetUp() <---- This is where i put the shadow extension
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            cellBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            cellBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            cellBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBackground.topAnchor, constant: 5),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBackground.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBackground.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBackground.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
            title.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellBackground.bottomAnchor, constant: -5)
        ])
        
        
    }()
```

I tried changing many different things, like putting the shadow on the cellBackground, just putting it as shadowSetUp(), and changing the bezier path to different versions, like using:

```
layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 15).cgPath
```

and

```
layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: <#T##UIRectCorner#>, cornerRadii: <#T##CGSize#>)
```

I also tried to remove the bezierPath, and it does work, but I know that for cells it is better to use bezierPath because of lagging issues.

I know that similar questions have been asked, but when I have looked around, nothing seems to work for me.
I looked at:

- [Shadow on UIView layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720473/shadow-on-uiview-layer)
- https://gist.github.com/nor0x/076cef18b1e412d2f432da911b9a5bab
- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/116678
- [Adding rounded corner and drop shadow to UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505379/adding-rounded-corner-and-drop-shadow-to-uicollectionviewcell)
- [How to make UICollectionViewCells have rounded corners and drop shadows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797111/how-to-make-uicollectionviewcells-have-rounded-corners-and-drop-shadows)
- [UICollectionView Cell Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488115/uicollectionview-cell-shadow)

I was just wondering where I was going wrong. When I has trying to recreate it, I couldn't get it to happen again.
If you have any questions please ask.
Thank you

Comment: If your code to add the shadows adds the correct effect to a UIView outside a CollectionViewCell and the problem only happens when you add the shadows to CollectionViewCells, also assuming that the code that adds the shadows applies to all cells similarly, my guess is that you are adding shadows multiple times to the same cell. So you have to make sure, as you scroll through your CollectionView, you are not adding shadow again and again to the same cell.

Comment: @Dogahe I thought the same thing, but when I comment out the line that creates the shadow, the shadow goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code below for making shadow.

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            myView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            myView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
            //myView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            myView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
            myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
            myView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
            myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        }
    }
```

Comment: does it matter that there is no shadow path?

Comment: I just tried it, but i gave it a shadow path, and it didn't work